# How to load an image for a rails controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to create a test in a rails application, but can't seem to find a way to load an image and them post it. I'm getting a **"uninitialized constant ActionController::TestUploadedFile (NameError)"** error (line 5) when I run the test.

```
context "testing user profile uploader" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, id: 123) }

  image = "base/app/assets/images/fallback/default.png"
  file = ActionController::TestUploadedFile.new image, "image/png"
  post :update, :user => { :profile_image => file }
  u = User.find(123)

  it "should be able to upload a user's profile image" do
    expect(u.profile_image.file).to be_equal "default.png"
  end

  it "should be able to find profile_avatar for the user's image" do
    expect(u.profile_image.versions[:profile_avatar].file).to be_equal "profile_avatar_default.png"
  end

  it "should be able to find small_avatar for the user's image" do
    expect(u.profile_image.versions[:small_avatar].file).to be_equal "small_avatar_default.png"
  end

  it "should be able to find avatar for the user's image" do
    expect(u.profile_image.versions[:avatar].file).to be_equal "avatar_default.png"
  end

  it "should be able to find large_avatar for the user's image" do
    expect(u.profile_image.versions[:large_avatar].file).to be_equal "large_avatar_default.png"
  end
end
```

What should I do to load the image? Sorry if the code is terrible, but I'm a ruby/rails novice.
Thanks!

---

Update: So, I changed the file according to your suggestion. The only problem now is that I get a **"`initialize': base/app/assets/images/fallback/default.png file does not exist (RuntimeError)"**, which makes sense since my image is not in the fixture folder. The application is a bit old so it doesn't have the project/fixtures folders.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the code from? `ActionController::TestUploadedFile` doesn't exist in Rails 4. Try this instead:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/fixture_file_upload

Answer (score 0):

TestUploadedFile moved in Rails 4.  You can find it at [`Rack::Test::UploadedFile`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/Rack/Test/UploadedFile).